# How to parse a JSON Response in React-Native

Tags: json, react-native, parsing, django-rest-framework, jsonparser

I have a JSON response from Django REST API like this:

```
[
{"email": "email1@gmail.com", "fullname": "fn1", "id": 1},
{"email": "email2@gmail.com", "fullname": "fn2", "id": 2}, 
{"email": "email3@gmail.com", "fullname": "fn3", "id": 3}, 
{"email": "email4@gmail.com", "fullname": "fn4", "id": 4},
{"email": "email5@gmail.com", "fullname": "fn5", "id": 5}
]
```

And I want to parse it in React native I used this code but it doesn't function for me I don't know why!

I'm a little bit new to this framework

```
import React , { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { View, ScrollView, Text,ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

const Information: () => React$Node = () => {
   
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch('http://192.168.1.18:8000/api/User')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => setData(json))
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    }, []);
  
    return (
        <>
            <ScrollView>
               <View>
                {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
        <View
          data={data} 
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text >{item.id},{item.email},{item.fullname}</Text>
          )}
        />
      )}        
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </>
    );
};

export default Information;
```

Comment: I think you need a  ```FlatList``` to do that, not a ```View``` , and remove ```ScrollView```.

Comment: I removed the `FlatList` because I was having a problem of using `FlatList` inside `ScrollView` and I am in need to use the `ScrollView` inside my code that's why I used `View` instead of `FlatList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an example of `FlatList`:

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView>
        <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.email} ... and other stuff</Text>}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
    </SafeAreaView>
)
```

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to fixe this `VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.` ??